# hashedSecret too short to be a bcrypted password not auth

Tags: postgresql, go

I'm adapting the login function from [this blogpost](http://shadynasty.biz/blog/2012/09/05/auth-and-sessions/). The User struct (see below) has four fields, id, name, email and password. You can see a row from the database below. The `fmt.Println`in the login function shows the user to be like this after the query to the database

```
 &{3 testuser $2a$10$hS7sth8jIBN2/IXFTWBibu3Ko5BXm9zHO5AJZRAbAOQ04uv.Gs5Ym [116 101 115 116 117 115 101 114 64 103 109 97 105 108 46 99 111 109]}
```

In other words, it has the `id` (3), the `name` (testuser), the hashed password, but then also an array of numbers which surprised me a bit because it's not in the row from the database (see below). You'll also notice that the `fmt.Println` is not displaying the email, even though that's visible in the row from the database, so there seems to be a problem here.

When bcrypt compares the hash and the password in the `Login` function, it's giving me this error

```
hashedSecret too short to be a bcrypted password not auth
```

Can you explain why this error's being thrown?

```
func Login(password, email string) (u *User, err error) {
    u = &User{}
    err = db.QueryRow("select * from users where email=$1 ", email).Scan(&u.Id, &u.Name, &u.Password, &u.Email)
    fmt.Println("u", u)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("err", err)
    }   

    err = bcrypt.CompareHashAndPassword(u.Password, []byte(password))
    if err != nil {
        u = nil
    }
    return
}
```

I have a user struct with the following fields

```
type User struct {
    Id       int
    Name     string
    Email    string
    Password []byte
}
```

I created a table for it in postgres like this

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."users" (
    "id" int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('users_id_seq'::regclass),
    "username" varchar(255) NOT NULL COLLATE "default",
    "email" varchar(255) NOT NULL COLLATE "default",
    "password" bytea 
)
WITH (OIDS=FALSE);
```

this is a row from the database

```
id |  username  |        email         |                                                          password                                                          
----+------------+----------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  3 | testuser   | testuser@gmail.com   | \x24326124313024685337737468386a49424e322f495846545742696275334b6f3542586d397a484f35414a5a524162414f51303475762e477335596d
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The array of numbers is the email address.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    email := []byte{116, 101, 115, 116, 117, 115, 101, 114, 64, 103, 109, 97, 105, 108, 46, 99, 111, 109}
    fmt.Println(email)
    fmt.Println(string(email))
}
```

Output:

```
[116 101 115 116 117 115 101 114 64 103 109 97 105 108 46 99 111 109]
testuser@gmail.com
```

---

After further study, I see you have `select *`. Don't do that! You get items returned by the database, not necessarily what you want. Always be explicit in the fields you want returned and their order.

From the `select *`, using the `CREATE TABLE` definition, you likely got `id`, `username`, `email`, and `password`. From your `Scan`, you set  `User` type `Id` to `id`, `Name` to `username`, `Password` to `email`, and `Email` to `password`. In other words, `u.Password` contains `email` (they have the same Go data type) and `email` is too short to masquerade as a hashed password.

Match the fields in the `select` and the `Scan`, for example,

```
"select id, username, password, email from users where email=$1 "

Scan(&u.Id, &u.Name, &u.Password, &u.Email)
```

Comment: thanks. If you can, please expand a bit to explain (I'd be very grateful and your answer only partially answers the question :)) so does that mean the email was somehow inserted into the password column (which is type []byte /bytea)? why is email like that? as you can see, it's supposed to be type `text` in the db? does this explain why the error in the title to the question is being thrown `hashedSecret too short to be a bcrypted password not auth`

Comment: thanks a lot, so what your saying in the second last paragraph of your answer is that Scan assigns the pointers to whatever column happened it happened to be numerically aligned with. `email` was third in the Create Table defintion, so the third argument passed to scan (Password) got assigned to email.

Comment: Correct - the order in which they are unmarshalled matters. The query just returns the rows, and Scan just puts them—one by one—into your struct fields in the order supplied, provided the types are compatible.

Comment: Yes, you can see this from the output of your `fmt.Println("u", u)` statement. It prints the `struct` fields in the order of the Go `User` type (`Id`, `Name`, `Email`, `Password`), but the values for the `u.Email` and `u.Password` fields are reversed.